# Conditional If Statement with change in method

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

I have this function that is supposed to loop through these additional functions while they won't take the totals up past 100. However, the iteration stops and I need it to finish up with the hunger and danger value either being 100 or 0 depending on which. The numbers that pass through are first: (50,50) second: (0, 100). I can't seem to figure out how to change the addition/subtractions amount when the if condition is no longer met. My consoles are all displaying the last iteration before going over the conditional values.

The problem is:

Create a function called frodo. frodo will take in two parameters:
startingHungerValue (Number) and startingDangerValue (Number).
frodo will need to store those values on internal variables.

frodo will then return an object with two methods:
The first method will be called dinnerOverFire.
dinnerOverFire will decrease hunger by 25 and will increase danger by 40.

The second method will be called hidingInBush.
hidingInBush will increase hunger by 35 and decrease danger by 20.

Both methods need to return an object structured like this:

{
  hunger: (modified hunger value),
  danger: (modified danger value)
}

NOTE: Neither hunger nor danger should be able to exceed 100 or drop below 0.

```
function frodo(startingHungerValue, startingDangerValue) {

  var shv = startingHungerValue;
  var sdv = startingDangerValue;

  console.log('startingHungerValue:', shv, 'startingDANGERvalue:', sdv)



  return {
    dinnerOverFire: () => {
      if ((shv >= 0 && shv < 101) && (sdv >= 0 && sdv < 101)) {
        return {
          hunger: shv - 25,
          danger: sdv + 40
        }
      }
    },
    hidingInBush: () => {
      if ((shv >= 0 && shv < 101) && (sdv >= 0 && sdv < 101)) {
        return {
          hunger: shv + 35,
          danger: sdv - 20
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By calling your `frodo()` function you will receive an object with two functions in it. However, these functions have never been called in your code snippet.

Comment: @cars10m there is a unit test that runs Frodo(). I just can’t get it to equal the 0 and 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly what you asked for, but I have a feeling you want to do something like below. It creates a `class` Frodo that you can call methods on like `eat` or `hide`.

You can see it in action here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agkyx65h/)

```
function Frodo(startingHungerValue, startingDangerValue) {
  var self = this; //this could change per scope, self keeps a reference to the basic of the class

  //store levels
  self.hunger = startingHungerValue;
  self.danger = startingDangerValue;

  //show levels method
  self.showLevels = function(){
    console.log('My hungerlevel: '+ self.hunger);
    console.log('My dangerlevel: '+ self.danger); 
    console.log('------'); 
  }

  //dinner method
  self.dinnerOverFire = function() {
    var newHunger = self.hunger - 25;
    var newDanger = self.danger + 40;

    if (newHunger<0) {
        newHunger = 0; //no negatives
    }

    if (self.hunger==0) {
        console.log('I\'m not hungry! No dinner!');
      console.log('------'); 
      return;       
    }
    if (newDanger>100) {
        console.log('Eating now would kill me! No dinner!');
      console.log('------'); 
      return;       
    }
    self.hunger = newHunger;
    self.danger = newDanger;

    console.log('Thanks for dinner!');
    self.showLevels();
  }

  //hiding method
  self.hideInBush = function() {
    var newHunger = self.hunger + 35;
    var newDanger = self.danger - 20;

    if (newDanger<0) {
        newDanger = 0; //no negatives
    }

    if (newHunger>100) {
        console.log('Hiding now would kill me! No hiding!');
      console.log('------'); 
      return;       
    }
    if (self.danger==0) {
        console.log('I\'m not scared at all! No hiding!');
      console.log('------'); 
      return;       
    }
    self.hunger = newHunger;
    self.danger = newDanger;

    console.log('Thanks, I feel safer already!');
    self.showLevels();
  }

  //initial message
  console.log('Hi, i\'m frodo!');
  self.showLevels();
}

//run your frodo
var frodo = new Frodo(50,50);
frodo.dinnerOverFire();
frodo.hideInBush();
frodo.dinnerOverFire();
frodo.hideInBush();
frodo.dinnerOverFire();
frodo.hideInBush();
frodo.dinnerOverFire();
```

This would output:

```
Hi, i'm frodo!
My hungerlevel: 50
My dangerlevel: 50
------
Thanks for dinner!
My hungerlevel: 25
My dangerlevel: 90
------
Thanks, I feel safer already!
My hungerlevel: 60
My dangerlevel: 70
------
Eating now would kill me! No dinner!
------
Thanks, I feel safer already!
My hungerlevel: 95
My dangerlevel: 50
------
Thanks for dinner!
My hungerlevel: 70
My dangerlevel: 90
------
Hiding now would kill me! No hiding!
------
Eating now would kill me! No dinner!
------
```

Which already shows a problem with the current way. At the end he's to scared to eat and to hungry to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, adding an else block to the `if` condition?

```js
function frodo(startingHungerValue, startingDangerValue) {
  var shv = startingHungerValue;
  var sdv = startingDangerValue;
  console.log('startingHungerValue:', shv, 'startingDANGERvalue:', sdv)
  return {
    dinnerOverFire: () => {
      if ((shv === 50 && shv === 50)){
        return {
          hunger: shv - 50,
          danger: sdv + 50
        }
      }
      else if ((shv >= 0 && shv < 101) && (sdv >= 0 && sdv < 101)) {
        return {
          hunger: shv + 100,
          danger: sdv - 100
        }
      }
    },
    hidingInBush: () => {
      if ((shv === 50 && shv === 50)){
        return {
          hunger: shv - 50,
          danger: sdv + 50
        }
      }
      else if ((shv >= 0 && shv < 101) && (sdv >= 0 && sdv < 101)) {
        return {
          hunger: shv + 100,
          danger: sdv - 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(frodo(50, 50).dinnerOverFire()); // 0,100

console.log(frodo(0, 100).dinnerOverFire()); // 100,0
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I’ll have to try the + 1 on the else blocks. I’ve tried manually setting the values on the else to the 0 and 100 but it didn’t pass the unit tests. I’ll try this way to see! I’ll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @GaelicLaic But what is the exact problem with your code? adding numbers should also be conditional is it?

Comment: My unit tests are still not passing. The first test is passing in 50,50 as the starting value and expecting 0,100. The second test passes 0,100 and expects 100,0. But I am still getting 25, 90 and 35, 80  instead. @NarenMurali

Comment: @GaelicLaic Classify which cases are special cases and write a separate if block, please check my updated answer!

Comment: I've added the problem to clarify what the expected return is. Let me know if you have any tips! Thank you! @NarenMurali

Comment: @GaelicLaic Seems like you need to sum or subtract the values with the input varaible  then apply the limiting condition, so add a ternary if so that if hunger > 100 then set it to 100, similarly if hunger < 0  set it to 0, but are the unit tests part of the question?

Comment: @GaelicLaic Any luck with solving this question?